# Calling a vector2 from another class

Tags: c#, class, variables, xna

I'm making a small game to fit in with XNA. And now I have a problem with calling a variable from another class.
I got a `Game1` and a `Player` class, now I want to call the player position in my `Game1` class. The position stored in a `Vector2` called `playerPosition`

```
public class Player
{
    //Playerinformation
    #region
    Texture2D playerImage;
    Vector2 playerPosition, tempCurrentFrame;
    float moveSpeed;
    float speed = 0.2f;
    #endregion
}

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{//Here i need the playerPosition, because i want to use it in the game class }
```

I hope you understand what I want and can help me.

Comment: Use `public Vector2 playerPosition { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Mohammad* suggested, you should declare:

```
public Vector2 playerPosition { get; set; }
```

or, if you only want to read that value and not to modify it, just do:

```
public Vector2 playerPosition { get; private set; }
```

Of course, in your `Game1` you have to declare a `Player player` variable (and call its constructor), so you can access that variable with `player.playerPosition`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked nice. And the thing with the private is a nice tipp also.